# CloudPagesURL() value not showing in HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to pass the email value from a data extension to HTML. I am using the CloudPagesURL() in my email in attempt to grab the subscriber's email.

Here is my code syntax that I am attempting to use:

Email Code:

```
<p><a title="MyPage" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(505,'Email Address',@EmailAddress))=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">Click to unsubscribe page 505</a></p>
```

CloudPage AMPScript Code:

```
%%[

VAR @emailAddress

SET @emailAddress = RequestParameter("emailaddr")

]%%
```

Cloudpage HTML Code:

```
<td width='155' valign='bottom'><input type='text' name='Name1' value='%%=v(@emailAddress)=%%' id='Name1' /></td>
```

Any reason as to why this doesn't work? My syntax might just be wrong or I might be using the CloudPagesURL() function incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to append the email address in your email.  It already exists in the built-in send context via the `emailaddr` personalization string.

**Email:**

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(505))=%%">Click to unsubscribe page 505</a>
```

**Page:**

```
%%[

VAR @emailAddress

SET @emailAddress = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work. Do you know if there is a function within AMPScript or SSJS that can grab the whole URL at the top and set it to a variable?

Comment: Yes.  For SSJS, there's an undocumented variable called `Platform.Request.RequestURL` and in AMPscript it's `RequestParameter('PAGEURL')`